# cloning project from GitHub failss

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, github, clone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEAmL.png)cloning project from GitHub fails and gives this error. I tried modifying things in AndroidManifest.xml and in java and nothing helps. please I'm been struggling with this for couple of days now so please help

Comment: where is the error?, attach error files

Comment: i putted a screenshot

Comment: Did you try the suggested methods in the error to overcome the depriciation problem?

Comment: add this to your android/app/src/main/androidmanifest.xml: android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
<mete-data
// add here above two lines
</application>

Answer (score 1):

you just need to upgrade the android project

to do that go to this link: https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration and complete the steps that stand there

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn to read error messages. The problem is clearly stated there. Sometimes, when such projects are downloaded, I simply create my own project, transfer all the files from lib there and modify the file pubspec,yaml